# How to find tinted covers for ceiling light fixture

Tags: lighting

I have a light on my ceiling, rather than being a socket with a bulb it is a ring of small LEDs with a plastic diffusing cover over top. I would love to play with the lighting, making it warner, or possibly deep blue, but I am not sure where to start - I'm wondering whether this is a generic light cover that I can replace with a tinted one or if such things are not standardized.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVqdV.jpg)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd3wy.jpg)

Comment: most likely not generic .... even if it was generic, it is doubtful that it would come in various colors .... you may have better luck installing an LED strip over top of the LED ring .............. you could also use a color gel sheet   https://www.amazon.com/lighting-gel-sheets/s?page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Alighting%20gel%20sheets

Comment: Yup, theater gel. As suggested by @jsotola.  I didn’t like the color of our covered deck lights after we switched them to LED, we were early adopters and there weren’t many non-harsh unnatural choices in LED, I experimented and settled on a really dark blue (which by coincidence doesn’t attract bugs).  After success there, the covered outdoor entry area in the front got a dose of purple/lavender that matches the colors there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to change the color character of the LED light a small amount using an alternate diffuser cover or by adding color filter sheets as mentioned in comments by @jsotola but I would comment that the results are not going to be optimum. Color filters work by allowing only certain ranges of wavelengths of light to pass through while others are rejected or attenuated by a large amount. With an LED light source, which are not broad spectrum devices, the resultant light level through the filter will likely not be particularly useful as a light source.

My suggestion would be to consider changing the character of that LED light fixture by **adding additional color selected light** to either the fixture or the room by installing an RGB LED light strip. These strips can be controlled to emit a huge selection of different colors that would increase the net light output into the room instead of reducing it.

You would have to install a separate power source and wiring for the RGB LED strip and it's color controller. If you try to do something inside the existing fixture you may have issues with safety where added low voltage circuitry is installed next to AC mains voltages so do consider the options very carefully before starting to experiment with these ideas.